# How do I add input data script in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: parameters, sas, enterprise-guide

Were using SAS Enterprise Guide V 7.13 HF1 (7.100.3.5419) (64-bit)
I'm currently running a SAS program from SAS Enterprise Guide. I have external parameters I pass to it when I run it on Linux. The command looks like this:

```
sas -noterminal -batch -log simple_run.log -print simple_run.lst -sysparm "beg_dt=2500,end_dt=2" simple_run.sas
```

How do I pass external parameters for beg_dt and end_dt to my program from SAS Enterprise Guide?

Answer (score 1):

In EG you can create a program node with the code

```
%let sysparm = beg_dt=2500,end_dt=2;
%include "simple_run.sas";
```

This presumes EG is using a profile that connects to a SAS Server on your Linux box, and simple_run.sas is in your home directory.

Comment: Great! Be sure to mark [answers to your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)